# How to disable a cookie from firing up at the website opening

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I block a certain cookie from firing up when opening the website using javascript? Then I need to allow this cookie if the user agrees to the cookie consent by clicking a button. Can I do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored on the end user's computer and can be read by any website. That said, cookies do not "fire up" when a website loads. It is up to you to properly add front-end or back-end mechanisms that will take advantage of said cookies. So if you intend to have a button you can set it so that clicking on the button will create a new cookie/sessionStorage variable (example: `enableOtherCookie`). This cookie/variable's existence will then be checked on subsequent pages before another JavaScript code block makes use of the cookie that requires the user's consent.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use an existing third party tool such as [Cookie Consent](https://cookieconsent.insites.com) which is free and open source. I'm not affiliated with them but just think it makes the process much easier.

The following example would insert a basic Cookie Consent popup requesting for opt-in permission before allowing the cookie. If your goal is to ensure GDPR compliance you will need to ensure tracking scripts, cookies etc. are all disabled in the `//disable cookies` section, and are only set when users opt-in - `//enable cookies`.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    onInitialise: function(status) {
      var type = this.options.type;
      var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
      if (type == "opt-in" && didConsent) {
        // enable cookies
      }
      if (type == "opt-out" && !didConsent) {
        // disable cookies
      }
    },
    onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
      var type = this.options.type;
      var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
      if (type == "opt-in" && didConsent) {
        // enable cookies
      }
      if (type == "opt-out" && !didConsent) {
        // disable cookies
      }
    },
    onRevokeChoice: function() {
      var type = this.options.type;
      if (type == "opt-in") {
        // disable cookies
      }
      if (type == "opt-out") {
        // enable cookies
      }
    },
    palette: {
      popup: {
        background: "#252e39"
      },
      button: {
        background: "#14a7d0"
      }
    },
    showLink: false,
    type: "opt-in"
  });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZdOGw?editors=1010)